# Read or pass data outside class of mouse event

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have a widget that uses rubberband to select region on an image, it can be editable on any aspect. I need to add functions that once the rubberband is placed it can be resizable or editable again so my idea is to save the region points(x,y,w,h) after the mouse release event.

But the problem now is how can I pass the data read in mouse release event outside my rubberband class.

Here is my code of drag and edit of rubberband.

```
class rubberBandWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.rubberBand = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
        self.tweaking = False
        self.tweakingpart = ""

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        pt = self.mapFromGlobal(event.globalPos())
        rg = self.rubberBand.geometry()

        if rg.isValid():
            tl, tr, bl, br = rg.topLeft(), rg.topRight(), rg.bottomLeft(), rg.bottomRight()
            off, offx, offy = QPoint(3, 3), QPoint(4, -3), QPoint(-3, 4)

            if QRect(tl - off, tl + off).contains(pt):
                self.tweakingpart = "topLeft";
                self.setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)
            elif QRect(tr - off, tr + off).contains(pt):
                self.tweakingpart = "topRight";
                self.setCursor(Qt.SizeBDiagCursor)
            elif QRect(bl - off, bl + off).contains(pt):
                self.tweakingpart = "bottomLeft";
                self.setCursor(Qt.SizeBDiagCursor)
            elif QRect(br - off, br + off).contains(pt):
                self.tweakingpart = "bottomRight";
                self.setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)
            elif QRect(tl + offx, tr - offx).contains(pt):
                self.tweakingpart = "top";
                self.setCursor(Qt.SizeVerCursor)
            elif QRect(bl + offx, br - offx).contains(pt):
                self.tweakingpart = "bottom"
                self.setCursor(Qt.SizeVerCursor)
            elif QRect(tl + offy, bl - offy).contains(pt):
                self.tweakingpart = "left";
                self.setCursor(Qt.SizeHorCursor)
            elif QRect(tr + offy, br - offy).contains(pt):
                self.tweakingpart = "right";
                self.setCursor(Qt.SizeHorCursor)

            if self.tweakingpart != "":
                self.tweaking = True
                return

        self.origin = pt
        self.rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.origin, QtCore.QSize()))
        self.rubberBand.show()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        pt = self.mapFromGlobal(event.globalPos())
        if self.tweaking:
            rg = self.rubberBand.geometry()
            if self.tweakingpart == "topLeft":
                rg.setTopLeft(pt)
            elif self.tweakingpart == "topRight":
                rg.setTopRight(pt)
            elif self.tweakingpart == "bottomLeft":
                rg.setBottomLeft(pt)
            elif self.tweakingpart == "bottomRight":
                rg.setBottomRight(pt)
            elif self.tweakingpart == "top":
                rg.setTop(pt.y())
            elif self.tweakingpart == "bottom":
                rg.setBottom(pt.y())
            elif self.tweakingpart == "left":
                rg.setLeft(pt.x())
            elif self.tweakingpart == "right":
                rg.setRight(pt.x())
            self.rubberBand.setGeometry(rg)
        else:
            self.rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.origin, pt).normalized())
```

And here is my code on release event and the data of (x, y, w, h) that need to be pass or read outside the class.

```
def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    self.tweaking = False
    self.tweakingpart = ""
    self.unsetCursor()

    if self.rubberBand.width() != 0 and self.rubberBand.height() != 0:
        print(self.rubberBand.x(), self.rubberBand.y(), self.rubberBand.width(), self.rubberBand.height())
```

I need the data every mouse release and save it. So once the user need to resize and edit again, my idea is to set the geometry of rubberband and re run the class so it can be editable again.

Comment: Do you want a QRubberBand that can be resized in several directions? I mean when you ask a question you should not ask about the possible solution that nobody guarantees works but about the main problem, that is called [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), please read the link for you to understand.

Comment: my Qrubberband code above is resizable. I need the data once the mouse release  event perform to pass outside the class and be callable. On my example once the release mouse event its just print my needed data. I just need to read outside the class.

Comment: okay, try my answer, if I help you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it check the [tour], that's the best way to thank.

Comment: @eyllanesc I already applied to my existing code and it works really fine. Thank you so much. This is my first time to encountered of exposing specific data on my class and I don't know it will need a signal. Thanks so much

Comment: I took the time to create a better implementation because if you want another widget to have that functionality you would have to copy all that code and that is not desirable, see my update.

Comment: Wow. This is great. Thank you so much and well appreciated your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to expose the data outside the class you should use signals as I show below:

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class rubberBandWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    rectChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QRect) # create signal
    ...
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.tweaking = False
        self.tweakingpart = ""
        self.unsetCursor()

        if not self.rubberBand.geometry().isNull():
            self.rectChanged.emit(self.rubberBand.geometry()) # emit signal


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = rubberBandWidget()
    def on_rectChanged(rect):
        # receiver
        print(rect.x(), rect.y(), rect.width(), rect.height())
    w.rectChanged.connect(on_rectChanged) # connect signal
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

On the other hand I see that your code is very coupled because if you want to use the same functionality in another widget you will have to copy all the code and that is not desirable, so I take the time to create a custom `QRubberband` that has that functionality, In the next part I show an example.

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class RubberBand(QtGui.QRubberBand):
    rectChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QRect)

    TopLeft, TopRight, BottomLeft, BottomRight, Top, Bottom, Left, Right, NonePos = range(9)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(RubberBand, self).__init__(QtGui.QRubberBand.Rectangle, parent)
        self._widget = None
        self.setWidget(parent)
        self.tweakingpart = RubberBand.NonePos

        self.cursors = [QtCore.Qt.SizeFDiagCursor,
                        QtCore.Qt.SizeBDiagCursor,
                        QtCore.Qt.SizeBDiagCursor,
                        QtCore.Qt.SizeFDiagCursor,
                        QtCore.Qt.SizeVerCursor,
                        QtCore.Qt.SizeVerCursor,
                        QtCore.Qt.SizeHorCursor,
                        QtCore.Qt.SizeHorCursor]

    def setWidget(self, widget):
        if widget is None:
            return
        if self._widget is not None:
            self._widget.removeEventFilter(self)
        self._widget = widget
        self._widget.installEventFilter(self)
        self.setParent(widget)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if self._widget is obj:
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
                self.handleMousePressEvent(event.pos())
                return True
            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove:
                self.handleMouseMoveEvent(event.pos())
                return True
            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
                self.handleMouseReleaseEvent(event.pos())
                return True
        return super(RubberBand, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

    def handleMousePressEvent(self, pt):
        rg = self.geometry()
        if not rg.isValid():
            return
        off, offx, offy = QtCore.QPoint(3, 3), QtCore.QPoint(4, -3), QtCore.QPoint(-3, 4)
        rect = QtCore.QRect(-off, off)
        tl, tr, bl, br = rg.topLeft(), rg.topRight(), rg.bottomLeft(), rg.bottomRight()
        for i, coord in enumerate([tl, tr, bl, br]):
            rect.moveCenter(coord)
            if rect.contains(pt):
                self.tweakingpart = i
        if QtCore.QRect(tl + offx, tr - offx).contains(pt):
            self.tweakingpart = RubberBand.Top
        elif QtCore.QRect(bl + offx, br - offx).contains(pt):
            self.tweakingpart = RubberBand.Bottom
        elif QtCore.QRect(tl + offy, bl - offy).contains(pt):
            self.tweakingpart = RubberBand.Left
        elif QtCore.QRect(tr + offy, br - offy).contains(pt):
                self.tweakingpart = RubberBand.Right

        if 0 <= self.tweakingpart < RubberBand.NonePos:
            self._widget.setCursor(self.cursors[self.tweakingpart])
            return
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(pt, QtCore.QSize()))
        self.show()

    def handleMouseMoveEvent(self, pt):
        rg = self.geometry()
        if 0 <= self.tweakingpart < RubberBand.NonePos:
            if self.tweakingpart == RubberBand.TopLeft:
                rg.setTopLeft(pt)
            elif self.tweakingpart == RubberBand.TopRight:
                rg.setTopRight(pt)
            elif self.tweakingpart == RubberBand.BottomLeft:
                rg.setBottomLeft(pt)
            elif self.tweakingpart == RubberBand.BottomRight:
                rg.setBottomRight(pt)
            elif self.tweakingpart == RubberBand.Top:
                rg.setTop(pt.y())
            elif self.tweakingpart == RubberBand.Bottom:
                rg.setBottom(pt.y())
            elif self.tweakingpart == RubberBand.Left:
                rg.setLeft(pt.x())
            elif self.tweakingpart == RubberBand.Right:
                rg.setRight(pt.x())
        else:
            rg = QtCore.QRect(rg.topLeft(), pt).normalized()
        self.setGeometry(rg)

    def handleMouseReleaseEvent(self, pt):
        self.tweakingpart = RubberBand.NonePos
        self._widget.unsetCursor()
        if not self.geometry().isNull():
            self.rectChanged.emit(self.geometry())


class TestWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TestWidget()
    rubberBand = RubberBand(w)
    def on_rectChanged(rect):
        print(rect.x(), rect.y(), rect.width(), rect.height())
    rubberBand.rectChanged.connect(on_rectChanged)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```